# what's the different bewteen docker stop and docker container stop?

Tags: docker

We can use [docker stop xxx](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) or [docker container stop xxx](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_stop/) to stop a container, but what's the difference between these? I looked at the official docs, the two commands had the same description and usage format.

Also, what's the **parent command** meaning in docker? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The main difference is that one is longer to type than the other to achieve the exact same result. `docker` is the parent of all other docker commands. `docker container` is the parent of all other `docker container xxx` subcommands, .... its basically a way to navigate the online doc hierarchically, not really anything else.

Comment: So, the **parent command** is only used to describe the hierarchy between commands for ease of reading, right? Just like the catalog of an article?

Answer (score 2):

Both are same. Some frequently used commands like `docker container stop` etc have shortened aliases under `docker` parent command.

Parent command is just the command one level up. For `docker container stop`, `stop` is the subcommand of `docker container` and `docker container` is called the parent command.